# next_post_link / previous_post_link not working with WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, navigation, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I am trying to add next and previous page buttons to my template, but when I try to use either `next_post_link` or `previous_post_link`, it just does not work.

Could it be because I am using `WP_Query`?

Here is my code thus far,

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

            <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
            <?php $args = array(
                "post_type" => "page", 
                "page_id" => $post->ID, 
                ); ?>

            <?php $query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

            <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>

                <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <!-- do stuff -->
                <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <div id="footer_nav_container">
                        <div class="left"><?php previous_post_link(); ?></div>
                        <div class="right"><?php next_post_link(); ?></div>
                    </div>

            <?php else: ?>
                <!-- do other stuff here -->                
            <?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Am I maybe missing essential parameters? From what I can see in the codex, it should work fine as I am using it now?

Answer (score 3):

`next_post_link` & `previous_post_link` work off the global `$wp_query`. You could simply overwrite the main query with `$wp_query =& $query`, **or** replace your custom query with the standard 'global' functions.

```
<?php query_posts( array( "post_type" => "page", "page_id" => $post->ID ) ) ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
        <!-- do stuff -->
    <?php endwhile ?>

    <div id="footer_nav_container">
        <div class="left"><?php previous_post_link(); ?></div>
        <div class="right"><?php next_post_link(); ?></div>
    </div>

<?php else : ?>

    <!-- do other stuff here -->

<?php endif ?>
```